# Plugin "react" was conflicted between ".eslintrc.js" and "BaseConfig

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb

[image]

After I set up ESLint, I got this error **Plugin "react" was conflicted between ".eslintrc.js" and "BaseConfig » /frontend/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-config-react-app/base.js".**

my .eslintrc.js is like

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
    'prettier',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
    '@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  ignorePatterns: [
    ".eslintrc.js"
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-use-before-define': "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "off",
    'import/prefer-default-export': "off",
    'import/extensions': [
      'error',
      {
        js: 'never',
        jsx: 'never',
        ts: 'never',
        tsx: 'never',
      },
    ],
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [
      'error',
      {
        extensions: ['.jsx', '.tsx'],
      },
    ],
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    'no-void': [
      'error',
      {
        allowAsStatement: true,
      },
    ],
    "react/function-component-definition": [
      2,
      { "namedComponents": "arrow-function" }
    ]
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        paths: ['src'],
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
      },
    },
  },
};
```

What I have done is

- npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
- yarn run eslint --init
- yarn add -D @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin @typescript-eslint/parser
- npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb

How can I remove this error ?

Answer (score 10):

You have to disable eslint while `react-scripts start`.

As of `react-scripts` v4.0.2, you can now opt out of ESLint with an environment variable. You can do this by adding it to your `.env` file, or by prefixing your scripts in your package.json file.

For example in `.env`:

```
DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true
```

Comment: Outstanding — I was able to create a production build without failure just by adding this line to the .env file. Many thanks.

Comment: i don't think disabling eslint is a solution, other than hiding the error. I was able to fix this by deleting lock file and re-running installer

Comment: eslint should be non-intrusive, if not disabling it completely is fair enough

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this problem in this way:
if you are using npm remove the package-lock.json file.
if you are using the yarn remove the yarn.lock file.

and then remove the node_module folder and install all of the dependencies again.

Answer (score 8):

You may need to dedupe eslint-plugin-react in your lockfile.

Comment: Running `yarn upgrade` sorted this for me.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed the issue by closing and reopening the project folder with code. There must have been a problem with the path name.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: What do you mean `I fixed the issue by closing and reopening the project folder with code`?

Comment: @UgniusMalūkas In a terminal cd into the project folder and type `code .`

Answer (score -3):

I faced the same error. After trying every solution I found on the internet, removing eslintrc.js actually helped.

Comment: removing `eslintrc.js` removes all the rules. I am not sure OP wanted to remove all linting rules.